# How can I set a string variable as a color in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, string, variables

I have an inputbox asking for a color, such as "red" or "green", however I want to have a subroutine set the background of a cell selection to that color, and not just have the word "red" or "green" pasted. Here is my code:

```
Sub backgroundcolor()
Dim color As String
color = InputBox("Enter color")
Range("A1:B5").Interior.ColorIndex = color
End Sub
```

How can I use the string (name of the color) and set the range of cells to that color?

Comment: You would need a function to translate the user-supplied color into either an index into the color palette or an RGB color value.  It's not clear though how many entries you want to support

Comment: ^^ Highly suggest you use RGB and `Interior.Color` instead of `Interior.ColorIndex`. There's resources online to explain the difference between the two. Unless you truly want an index in the current color palette.

Comment: You could use a switch, e.g., `Select Case cell(r,c).value` // `Case "red"  Interior.color = vbRed`

Comment: Or use a lookup table - https://cloford.com/resources/colours/namedcol.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub backgroundcolor()
    Dim color As String
    color = InputBox("Enter color")
    If color = "" Then Exit Sub
    sColorsNameArr = Array("Black","White","Red","BrightGreen","Blue","Yellow","Pink","Turquoise","DarkRed","Green","DarkBlue","DarkYellow","Violet","Teal","Gray25","Gray50","PowderBlue","Plum","Cream","LightTurquoise","DarkPurple","Salmon","NavyBlue","LightLavender","DarkBlue2","Pink2","Yellow2","Turquoise2","Violet2","DarkRed2","Teal2","Blue2","SkyBlue","LightTurquoise2","LightGreen","LightYellow","PaleBlue","Rose","Lavender","Tan","LightBlue","Aqua","Lime","Gold","LightOrange","Orange","BlueGray","Gray40","DarkTeal","SeaGreen","DarkGreen","OliveGreen","Brown","Plum2","Indigo","Gray80") ' all 56 colors
    pos = Application.Match(color, sColorsNameArr, False)

    If Not IsError(pos) Then
       Range("A1:B5").Interior.ColorIndex = pos
    Else
       MsgBox color & " not found!"
    End If

End Sub
```